# A simple expression which Mathematica will not simplify

Tags: equation-solving

Sorry for the vague title, but I wasn't sure how to phrase this.

I was using *Mathematica* to solve a fairly simple algebraic equation, but when I tried to substitute the solution into the original equation as a check, I can't seem to recover my original answer. Minimal example:

```
eq = a == (1 - b)/Sqrt[1 - 2 b]

sol = Solve[eq, b]

FullSimplify[(1 - b)/Sqrt[1 - 2 b] /. sol, a > 0]
```

The final line outputs

> ```
> {(a (a + Sqrt[-1 + a^2]))/Sqrt[-1 + 2 a (a + Sqrt[-1 + a^2])], 
>  (a (a - Sqrt[-1 + a^2]))/Sqrt[-1 + 2 a (a - Sqrt[-1 + a^2])]}
> ```

even after I've specified that a is positive. So `FullSimplify` is not enough to make this last line output `a`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to demonstrate is to 'take care of' of the square root:
Rewriting:

```
eqn = (1 - b)/Sqrt[1 - 2 b];
sol = Solve[eqn == a, b];
```

Now,

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[eqn^2 /. sol], a > 0]
```

yields:

```
{a, a}
```